# Making Perl print in runtime?

Tags: perl

I have this piece of code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
open my $output, ">", "D:\\abc.txt";
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
    print $output $i . "\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

Surprisingly, when I run it and open abc.txt in the 50 seconds while the machine is running, I don't see the current output. I would expect that after 13 seconds, for example, the file would include "0\n1\n2", but it doesn't, for some reason.

I reviewed other pieces of code which I wrote and actually do that, but I couldn't find any difference.

Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Please search before posting a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep function in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558634/sleep-function-in-perl)

Comment: An alternative to using double backslashes `\\ ` for windows paths is forward slash `/`: `"D:/abc.txt"`. You may also consider `'D:\abc.txt'`

Comment: You're [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Comment: Zaid - Thank you for your answer. I'm very sorry, I simply did not know what to search for. As said, for some reason setting $| to 1 doesn't solve the problem.
TLP - Thanks a lot, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: So, how do you know you even opened the file successfully?  I don't see any checking of the return value of `open`.  Similarly, how do you know that `print` worked?

Comment: I know all of these actions were successful because after the machine stops running, I open abc.txt and see 0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n...

Comment: It's been asked many times, and is even in perlfaq5.  But more often than not I see people forgetting that $| does not universally apply to all filehandles.  Even in quick responses here that fact seems to get overlooked soemtimes.  One must select the filehandle to which it should be applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read Marc Jason Dominus's article, [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) you will see that setting `$|` applies to the current filehandle.  If you set `$| = 1;` near the top of your script, you're probably turning off buffering for STDOUT.  Yet your script is writing to a filehandle named `$output`.

You should put this line in your script immediately following the `open` call.

```
select( ( select( $output ), $|=1 )[0] ); # borrowed from the Suffering from Buffering article.
```

This trick selects the `$output` filehandle, turns buffering off, then reselects the originally selected filehandle (presumably STDOUT) so that the rest of your script doesn't start using $output unknowingly.

This is also documented in [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle?--Why-must-I-do-this?), which comes standard with every complete Perl installation.

As a best practice, you probably should also either be putting `or die $!` after all IO calls, or `use autodie;` at the top of your script.  I say 'probably' because there are always exceptions, but it's unlikely that this is one of them.

Comment: Hi David - thank you so much for your answer, that was the problem. I am so sorry that I didn't see it myself in the article, I was only reviewing it because I thought it suggested the same solution as the others have.

I still don't understand why, then, I didn't have to put that in my other codes...

Comment: Without seeing other code it would only be a guess.  But Perl does flush output buffers when they fill up, when their filehandle is closed (including upon program termination, or when a lexical filehandle passes out of scope), and in the case of terminal output, upon encountering a newline character. If the answer worked, accept. ;)

Comment: Yes, I did realise that when encountering a newline character, Perl flushes - this is why I found the example in my question so strange, because it does use a newline character! Yes, the answer did worked, and I did accept. :-)

Comment: The newline autoflush applies to terminal streams (STDOUT to a terminal).  ...and thanks. :)